# the each function

Tags: jquery, each

hii  I have a 680 buttons in a page, and I want to run a function on them all with the each function.  here is the code:

```
$("button#check_all").button().click(function(){
    btns=$(".viewport").find('.third_cat_chb');//here are all 680 btns
    this_btn=$(this);
    count=btns.size(); //680
    cpt=0;
    btns.each(function(){
        cpt += 100/count;
        if($(this).is(".cat_chb_off")){
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value : cpt});
    });
    $("#progressbar").hide('slow');
});
```

The problem is that I want to see the buttons changed immediately when I click to select them all, not to set interval but to finish each button alone and online.
but what really happens is that the site is stuck over 35 seconds and I see the buttons changed suddenly.

Comment: It sounds like the large number of buttons is bogging down the client side. It also depends on what's going on in the `click` function for each item. If you're trying to get a threaded look and feel, you'll need to use threads or some other asynchronous technology (probably with callbacks). Can you post a little bit of sample html?

Comment: it's not about the 680 buttons. I tried to limit the buttons into 30 only, and I get the same result!!

Comment: what is happening in the click functions? if you cut the button count down to 30 (1 twentieth) it still takes 35 seconds?

Comment: no, it takes about 2-3 seconds

Comment: How can you call that the same result!? Help me help you. And how many times can I ask - what is taking place in your click function. For each button, you are triggering the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer:

```
//check buttons:
$("button#check_all").button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-battery-3"
    },
    text: false
}).click(function(){
    btns=$(".viewport").find('.third_cat_chb');
    this_btn=$(this);
    count=btns.size();
    move_over(0,1);
});

function move_over(i, time){
    var btn = btns.eq(i);
    cpt += 100/count;
    if(btn.is(".cat_chb_off")){
        btn.trigger('click');
    }
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value : cpt});
```

as you can see, I don't use each at all!!
        setTimeout(function(){
            move_over(++i, time);
        }, time)
    }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the progressbar, you didn't simply set the value inside the each, you're initializing it on every loop.

Initialize the progressbar outside the each, inside the each only set the value:

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value", cpt );
```

However, it will depend on the browser if you see any changes (in the progressbar or buttons), it's a really quick process with the suggested modification and usually browsers did not newly render things when you're inside a loop.

Comment: it's not the progessbar only.. it's also the buttons.

Comment: No, with the changes it takes 200ms for me with 1000 buttons.